# Initializing bloc in provider constructor vs initializing inline declaration of the bloc instance variable

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

After creating a Bloc Provider class that extends an InheritedWidget, what is the difference between initializing the bloc instance variable inside the Provider constructor and initializing it while declaring the variable?

```
class CommentsProvider extends InheritedWidget {

  final CommentsBloc bloc;

  CommentsProvider({Key key, Widget child})
    : bloc = CommentsBloc(),
      super(key: key, child: child);
}

class CommentsProvider extends InheritedWidget {

  final CommentsBloc bloc = CommentsBloc();

  CommentsProvider({Key key, Widget child})
    : super(key: key, child: child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two are strictly equivalent, but both options are bad.

You should **not** create mutate data inside an *Inheritedwidget*.You could easily loose your state and it is considered bad practice.

Instead consider wrapping your *Inheritedwidge*  into a *StatefulWidget*, or use a package such as `provider`.

Using `provider`, you don't need to make such class anymore. Instead you can directly do:

```
Provider(
  builder: (_) => CommentsBloc(),
  dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
  child: Whatever(),
)
```